# Facebook Graph API - Marketing Insights Edge Error 500

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, error-handling, facebook-c#-sdk, http-error

I'm trying to extract ads insights in a time range using .NET Facebook SDK.
I have 80 advertising accounts and all of them should be processed in a daily basis.
All advertising metrics should be extracted (it's like 70 or 80)

This is the endpoint i'm accessing to make requests:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{AdAccount}/insights?fields={fields}&level=ad&time_range[since]={begin_date}&time_range[until]={end_date}
```

I've made several attempts without luck.

1. I've tried sequential requests one per ad account on level = Ad
2. I've tried parallel requests in order to make it faster
3. I've tried batch requests also to try to improve the performance

All these tries takes long time to process also I don't understand why some requests give me **Error 500, Code: 1 Unknown error**, because these errors are not linear, they occur occasionally in different requests.

I would like to know what are the best practices to extract this amount of information for all ad accounts without errors, or at least handling them until I have a successful answer.

**UPDATE**

I'm not really sure what's happening, i've made two simple requests

```
act_107********/insights?level=ad OK
act_138********/insights?level=ad NOT OK
```

Both accounts are active and have active ads as well.

Comment: If the data set you are requesting causes to much CPU load or takes to much time, Facebook might simply kill off an API request. Are you trying to request all 80 metrics in one request? If so, it might make sense to split that up into several individual requests.

Comment: @CBroe In the same simple request for 2 different accounts act_X_1/insights?level=ad and act_X_2/insights?level=ad, 1 returns data and 2 error 500 code 1

Answer (score 0):

An ad account may have many campaigns, each has many ad sets, and each has many ads. So when you call the API to get all the insights of all ads of an ad account, it may be just too much data to be handled quickly enough. And ad account level insight call is the choice for the small customers, like with 10 campaigns. The reason of why one ad account is fine and another is not is that the first account has more ads than the second.

What you should do is to get the insights campaign by campaign, or even ad sets by ad sets (if you have like 1 big campaign with tons of ad sets). Also, you can limit the time range to retrieve only the data you need.

So, how many ads are considered as "too many"? There is not such a number, as some ads are complicated and some are simple. It also depends on which fields you want to include in your insights call. In general, if you get so many errors that you need to ask a question here, it's a good sign that you should break down your calls now.